# Update git commit author date when amending

Tags: git

I found myself amending my commits quite often. I don't `stash` so much because I tend to forget I did so, especially when I want to save what I did before I leave or before a weekend, so I do a "draft" commit. Only thing is, when I amend the commit, it is still set to the original author date. Is there a (simple) way to update it when amending?

Comment: This is especially useful when you perform interactive rebase and expect GitHub to display the commits in the Pull Request in tree order instead of date order.

Answer (score 464, accepted):

You can change the author date with the `--date` parameter to `git commit`.  So, if you want to amend the last commit, and update its author date to the current date and time, you can do:

```
git commit --amend --date="$(date -R)"
```

(The `-R` parameter to `date` tells it to output the date in RFC 2822 format.  This is one of the [date formats understood by `git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_date_formats).)

Comment: FTR, looks like on OS X, `date` doesn't know `-R`. Using `date` without options did the job anyway

Comment: Note that if you want this as an alias you need to add a `!` and escape the quotation marks, e.g. `can = !git commit --amend --date=\"$(date -R)\"`

Comment: `date -R` doesn't work on OSX, use `date +%s` instead

Comment: Idem for FreeBSD: `git commit --amend --date="$(date +%s)"`

Comment: So you commit first and then run this?

Comment: `git commit --amend --date="'$(date -R)'"` generates this error for me in bash (Debian7):  
`error: unknown option 'amend --no-edit --date='Tue, 10 Mar 2015 17:53:06 -0700''`  
and `git commit --amend --date="$(date +%s)"` generates this error:  
`error: unknown option 'amend --date=1426035358'`.  
can anyone tell me why?

Comment: @maurice: I don't think those can be exactly the commands you typed: in the first instance, for example, the output you quote suggests you'd also supplied `--no-edit`. I can reproduce what you're seeing under bash in Debian 7 only if i put a ``\`` before the spaces after options or put quotes from `amend` to the end of `date` - in other words, escaping so that bash is treating everything after the first `--` as one option argument.

Comment: @stash Unless you're using the GNU implementation of date. ;)

Comment: @EpicDavi yes, commit first and run it after :)

Comment: How can I pass it the date of another commit from git show ?

Comment: `git commit --amend --date=now` works also. No need to invoke a subshell with the **date(1)** command.

You can see it in the source code of **git(1)** in [date.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c#L938)

'now' is a special value which is converted using date_now() function. Same for 'noon', 'yesterday', 'midnight', 'tea' and others listed in the structure array special[].

Comment: How can I retroactively do this if I already have commits amended and commit dates all over the place?

Comment: The `--no-edit` flag is also handy (not for original question necessarily but related questions certainly).

Comment: The general applicability of this comment might be limited, but if ending here because of `git commit --amend --date='now'` appears to not be working. Do make sure the clock is actually correctly set on the machine where you are running the command.

Comment: Annoying that `--date` is not equivalent to `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=... git commit --amend` (`--date` works, env var does not - unless I messed up in my attempt)

Answer (score 443):

As of Git v2.1.4 (tested on Debian 8 (Jessie))

```
git commit --amend --date=now --no-edit
```

`--amend`: edit last commit

`--date=now`: set date to current date

`--no-edit`: don't edit commit message

Comment: And if you don't want to see the commit message again, add `--no-edit`.

Answer (score 320):

Another way to do this is

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

This does change the commit author as well as the date - but if it was originally your unpushed commit then that's a no-op.

You can also add `--no-edit` if you want to update the date on multiple commits but you want the commit messages to stay untouched. This way you will not be prompted to edit the message for each commit.

Comment: Single copy-paste: `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit`

Comment: --reset also works, slightly shorter

Answer (score 24):

I like Mark's answer and used it myself several times, but now I'm on OS X and `date -R` is not supported. But everything is much easier than original answer made us think, just use **empty string**!

```
git commit --date= --amend
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also try

```
git commit --date="$(date)" --amend
```

Or in new versions of git

```
git commit --date=now --amend
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Git aborts with the error `fatal: invalid date format:`

Comment: Worked for me (on Windows, Git 1.9.4)

Comment: Better to use `--date="$(date)"` in OS X. The option `-R` is GNUism.

Answer (score 3):

I created this npm package if someone still looking for a simple way to change dates of multiple commits.

https://github.com/bitriddler/git-change-date

Usage:

```
npm install -g git-change-date
cd [your-directory]
git-change-date
```

Comment: I appreciate automating things like this for better workflow. Thank you for the `npm` package. @Urda why discourage people from automating things if that solution makes their workflow better?

Answer (score 3):

There are two dates on a commit

- The author date records when the commit was originally made; it can be specified with `--date` command-line argument
- The commit date is updated changed every time a commit is modified; it can be specified using `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment varable

To change both of then you can do this:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
```