# Can GIT_COMMITTER_DATE be customized inside a git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I'd like to manually control the git commit timestamp so that my GIT_COMMITTER_DATE always matches the GIT_AUTHOR_DATE.  I've seen many solutions using filter-branch to rewrite history, but I'd rather be proactive about this and put the logic in a git hook so that it always matches going forward.

But I find that while these variables work fine if defined in the environment where git is invoked, they do not seem to have any effect when they are defined inside the pre-commit git hook.  Eg:

```
# this works if run directly on cmd line, but not inside the pre-commit hook
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Mon, 11 Aug 2014 11:25:16 -0400'
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"
```

Is there any way to dynamically adjust these values inside a git hook so that commits automatically have the desired timestamps?  I'm on git version 1.8.5.2

Comment: You are aware that according to [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/cg-commit.1.html), GIT_COMMITTER_DATE "should be never overridden, unless you know you absolutely need to override it (to ensure the commit gets the same ID as another or when migrating history around)"?

Comment: These variables are provided for the express purpose of manipulation, which is routinely done on the command line.  What difference does it make if I now want to do that same manipulation in a git hook?

Comment: that's not really true, as command line affects author date only, not committer date. You can't change committer date from the command line variables, only through environment variables. But no, I don't know the root cause why the man page says so.

Comment: I've been using aliases as a ugly workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832219/can-i-hide-commits-time-when-i-push-to-github It's sad.

Answer (score 5):

**`post-commit` hook + `git commit --amend`**

This is not super elegant, but it seems to work and sets both committer and author date:

.git/hooks/post-commit

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z "${GIT_COMMITTER_DATE:-}" ]; then
  d="$(date --iso-8601=seconds)"
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$d" git commit --amend --date "$d" --no-edit
fi
```

Don't forget to:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
```

We check for `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to prevent it from entering into an infinite commit loop, and it also skips the hook if the user is already passing a specific time.

Here is a more sophisticated example that uses the date from previous commits through `git log` and `date` manipulations: [Can I hide commits' time when I push to GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832219/can-i-hide-commits-time-when-i-push-to-github/52887876#52887876)

Remember that the committer date still leaks on `git rebase`, but that can be solved with a `post-rewrite` hook: [git rebase without changing commit timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps/53516609#53516609)

Then there is also `git am`, which can be solved with `--committer-date-is-author-date` as mentioned at: [git rebase without changing commit timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps/)

The `--amend --date` part was asked at: [Update git commit author date when amending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110310/update-git-commit-author-date-when-amending/13497026)

You could also set that to a global hook: [Applying a git post-commit hook to all current and future repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/applying-a-git-post-commit-hook-to-all-current-and-future-repos/37293198#37293198) but `core.hooksPath`  prevents local hooks from running at all which might be a problem.

Tested on Git 2.19.